# Number of leaves in a tree with maximum degree $k$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

Let $G$ be a tree with a maximum degree of the vertices equal to $k$.
**At least** how many vertices with a degree of $1$ can be in $G$ and why?

I think the answer must be $k$ but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that in a tree with maximum degree $k$, there are at least $k$ leaves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427680/prove-that-in-a-tree-with-maximum-degree-k-there-are-at-least-k-leaves)

Answer (score 2):

**HINT.** Let $G$ be a smallest tree that meets the requirements. Could adding nodes to $G$ decrease the answer?

Answer (score 1):

For $d\in\{1,\dots,k\}$, let $n_d$ be the number of nodes of degree $d$.  By the handshake lemma, we have
$$\sum_{d=1}^k d n_d = 2\left(\sum_{d=1}^k n_d - 1\right),$$
which implies that
$$n_1 = 2 + \sum_{d=3}^k (d-2) n_d \ge 2 + (k-2) n_k \ge 2 + (k-2) 1 = k.$$
This lower bound is attained by a star with $k+1$ nodes.

---

Alternatively, perform a depth-first search rooted at a node with degree $k$.  Each branch yields at least one leaf.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Any tree on $\geq 2$ vertices has at least two leafs. Consider a tree with maximal degree $k$ and delete a vertex $v$ with degree $k$. You are left with a forest consisting of $k$ components, coming with a distinct neighbor $v_i$ of $v$ in $T$. Finish by making a case distinction on whether the components have 1 or more vertices and using the first sentence.