# How to prove that the degree of every vertices is not bigger then then the number of leaves in a graph tree.

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I need to prove that if we have a tree (undirected connected graph with no cycles) with $k$ leaves, then for every vertices in the tree:
$\deg(v)\leq k$.

Is this possible to prove by induction? Or any other way?
I tried to do it in different ways.

First I tried to prove it by induction on the number of vertices in a tree.
Let tree $G$ have $k$ leaves and $n$ vertices.
Base of induction: $n=2$
If $n=2$ then there is one edge that connects the two nodes. So every node has a degree of one meaning there are two leaves in the tree and every vertices has a degree that is less then the number of leaves.
We assume by induction:
We have a tree $G$ with $n$ vertices and $k$ leaves, every node has a degree that is not bigger than $k$.

Induction step: lets add a new vertices to the graph.
We can add it to a leaf or a vertices that isn't a leaf.
If we add it to a leaf then the number of leaves in the tree doesn't change, the only degree that changes is the leaf's degree it becomes $2$. The number of leaves in a  tree is at least $2$. So the degree of the once leaf is  not bigger than the number of leaves.if we add it to a node that isn't a leaf the number of leaves become bigger by one. The degree to the vertice is bigger by one. Before adding the leaf the degree was.
$\deg(v)\leq k$ after adding the leaf it becomes $\deg(v)+1\leq k+1$  which is still not bigger then then the number of leaves.
I don't feel like this  induction is  right.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Sorry ,I am new to this website. What does my question lack exactly?

Comment: For instance, what did you try?

Comment: Your reasoning is not very correct. Several different proofs of this statement are offered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427680)